# Fetching data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

Javascript.
This works:

```
var snapshot = db.collection('xyz').doc("ABCD").get().then((snapshot) => {...
```

the omitted code delivers the content of ABCD to the console.log
but this doesn't:

```
var snapshot = db.collection("xyz").where("ownkey","==","ABCD").get().then((snapshot) => {...}
```

A snapshot.exists test fails.  I've checked the obvious, the case of the letters in ownkey agrees with the document and I'm stuck.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The instance of object that will be returned from those 2 code are different.

1. By using `.doc()`

The value that will be returned is the instance of [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which contain the data of the single document you request.

---

2. By using `.where()`

This means you want to **search** something and it will return the data as the instance of [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). which can contain 0 or more of the document data like an array. (This instance doesn't contain `.exists` property so this might failed your test)

So if you want to check that the search found something (Contain 1 or more of the document data), you can use [`.empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) to check it

```js
snapshot.empty
```

or if you want to retrieve the data from it, you may need to use [`.forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) to loop all the data out from that instance

```js
snapshot.forEach(docSnap => {
  // docSnap is like a normal DocumentSnapshot.
})
```

Comment: In addition to this, I'd also recommend getting into the habit of using `docSnap`/`docSnapshot` and `querySnapshot` in your code instead of just `snapshot`. Even better if you include what the documents are such as `userDocSnap` and `postDocSnap`.

Comment: This is so helpful - its so hard to find out these wrinkles in firebase without having experts to ask.  thank you!